# How to prove this statement? (independent normal random variables).

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

> Given $X,Y$ defined on the same probability space, let $E(X)\ge E(Y)$. 
> Prove or disprove: 
> a. if $X,Y$ are independent then $P(X\ge Y)\ge 0.5$. 
> b. if $X,Y$ are independent, and have standard normal distribution ($N(0,1$)), then $P(X\ge Y)\ge 0.5$.

**My attempt:** 
For the first statement, intuitively, if a random variable receives lots of negative numbers, and one big positive number with a low probability, the expected value can go up drastically, so I started to search for examples: 
$P(X=-5)=0.95$, and $P(X=10000)=0.05.$ 
$E(X)=495.25$. 
Now, if I chose $Y=4$, then $E(Y)=4$. 
I'm just a little bit confused of how to conduct the calculations formally for $P(X\ge Y)$, I know that on $0.95$ probability, $X$ will be less than $Y$, because that's how I defined it. But I'm wondering if theres any formal way to play with $P(X \ge Y)$ to reach that statement of mine mathematically. 
For the second statement, I know that if $X,Y$ are independent and normal, then they're a part of a gaussian vector, which means every linear transformation of them is also a normal random variable. 
So I've tried to do this $P(X\ge Y)=P(X-Y \ge 0). $ And then let $Z=X-Y$. 
So $E(Z)=E(X)-E(Y)$. and $Var(Z)=Var(X-Y)=Var(X)+Var(-Y)=Var(X)+Var(Y).$
But I'm stuck here, how do I proceed to show that $P(Z \ge 0)\ge 0.5?$
Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: a) $\mathbb P\{X\geq Y\}=\mathbb P\{X=10000\}$. b) $\mathbb P\{X>Y\}=\int_{\mathbb R}\int_{-\infty }^x f_{X}(x)f_Y(y)dydx$.

Comment: Keep in mind that to disprove a statement all you need is to give a counter-example i.e. an example where the statement is clearly not true.

Comment: "... how do I proceed to show that $P(Z\geq0)$?...". Don't you mean: "... how do I proceed to show that $P(Z\geq0)\geq0.5$?..."? Your $Z=X-Y$ has normal distribution with mean $0$. That tells us that its distribution is continuous and symmetric wrt $0$. So $P(Z\geq0)=P(Z\leq0)=0.5$.

Comment: @drhab Thank you for the help, and yes, just fixed the mistake. But what do you mean it is a normal distribution with mean $0$? did you mean because that $E(X)\ge E(Y)$ that means $E(Z) \ge 0$, thus $Z$ has a mean which is greater or equal zero, which means its symmetric somewhere in the positive side of $x$ axis, and that just makes $P(Z \ge 0) \ge 0.5$? I'm not sure if I got the idea correctly

Comment: It is well known that a (non-degenerated) linear combination of two rv's that have a joint normal distribution have again normal distribution. Here $X$ and $Y$ are independent and both have normal distribution. That implies that they indeed have a joint normal distribution. Conclusion: $Z=X-Y$ has normal distribution. This with $\mathbb EZ=\mathbb EX-\mathbb EY=0-0=0$. That is all we need to conclude that $P(Z\geq0)=0.5$.

Comment: @drhab I understand that if they're independent normal distributions then any linear transformation is normal distribution, but what makes their expected values equal? is it because we know that they are a part of a multivariate normal vector, and that means they have the same expected value and variance?

Comment: No. It is because you state under b) the rvs $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution: standard normal. That makes their expected values equal.

Comment: @drhab Ohhhh I completely missed that! Thanks so much for all the help!